# Can uniform local integrability implies uniform local absolute continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $u\in L_{u,}^{loc}$, i.e., 
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\int_{|x-y|<1}|V(y)|dy<\infty
$$
then can we obtain that $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a $r>0$, such that 
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\int_{|x-y|<r}|V(y)|dy<\epsilon
$$
?
If this is not true, are there any counterexamples ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n = 1$ for simplicity. Let

$$V = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k\cdot \chi_{[3k-1/k,3k+1/k]}.$$

Then

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \int_{\lvert x-y\rvert < 1} \lvert V(y)\rvert\,dy = 2,$$

and for all $1 \geqslant r > 0$, we also have

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \int_{\lvert x-y\rvert < r} \lvert V(y)\rvert\,dy = 2.$$